# Definition of $c$-IPP Codes

Tags: coding-theory

I am reading [this](http://file:///home/dell/Downloads/Fernandez-Urroz2022_Article_AStudyOfTheSeparatingPropertyI.pdf) paper named "A study of the separating property in Reed Solomon Codes by bounding the minimum distance".

Here the author has first informally defined the $c$-Identifiable Parent Property (IPP) Codes.

---

*Informal Definition:* A code $\mathcal{C}$ is said to have $c$-IPP property if all coalitions of atmost $c$ traitors that can generate the same pirate copy have a non-empty intersection, i.e. have a common traitor.

*Formal Definition:* A code $\mathcal{C}$ defined over $\mathbb{F}_q$ has the $c$-Identifiable Parent Property ($c$-IPP), $c>0$ if for all $z \in \mathbb{F}_q^n$ and for all coalitions $T \subseteq \mathcal{C}$ of atmost $c$ codewords we have
$$
z \notin \bigcup_{T ; |T| \le c} desc(T) \ \ \ \text{or} \ \ \ \bigcap_{z \in desc(T)} T \ne \phi 
$$

---

My Question:

1. How to relate $z \notin \bigcup_{T ; |T| \le c} desc(T)$ with the informal definition?
2. Can I call every element $z \in desc(T)$ a pirate copy genrated by a colation $T \subseteq \mathcal{C}$ ?

Comment: did you see my answer

Comment: @kodlu yes. The definition is clear to me now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The property $z \notin \bigcup_{T ; |T| \le c} desc(T)$ refers to those words in the space that are NOT generatable by coalitions of size at most $c$; this way the formal definition can be written for all words in the space. The second part of the formal definition has to do with identifiability and applies to all those words that can be generated by a coalition with at most $c$ members.
2. Every element $z\in desc(T)$ is a *possible* pirate copy that *could have been generated* by a coalition $T$ of size $\leq c.$